# Is there a way to grab the most up-to-date CSV (appends every 5 mins) file into my Rust program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, rust, rust-tokio

I have a python script that runs in the background which creates a csv file and appends new lines to the CSV file every 5 minutes when new data comes in. I would like to read this CSV file in my Rust application but also grab the new changes when new data comes in.

I see you can use the notify crate to check for changes in a directory or file. Would this be a good way to go about it?

Does anyone have a solution for this? Every row has timestamps in the CSV file and I can also get sequence number/index in the CSV if that can help. Thank you so much!

I have managed to read an entire CSV file and store it as records in Rust via tutorials but I don't understand how to scan for changes and add the new records into the rust program. I have also tried to use the notify crate separately but I am not sure if I need a debouncer to scan for changes in the csv file or use the regular example in the docs.

Using csv package with serde in Rust.

Comment: Can you make changes to the python script? Which OS is this running on? I could imagine reading from the file while it's being written to  causing problems.

Comment: Yes I can. Testing on OSX but should be running on ubuntu server at some point. This way sounded easier than making a rest api on Rust and having python script send the data over as json. Thanks!

Comment: You might not need to go as far as a rest service. If you create a [named pipe](https://linuxiac.com/how-to-use-pipes-and-named-pipes-in-linux-explained-with-examples/), then have the python script write each new entry to it, the rust app can read new data as it comes in.